# How do I write every fact of a certain term to a file?

Tags: java, stream, prolog, logic, gnu

I'm trying to write my results to a file. I'm doing this with GNU Prolog (or rather, GNU Prolog for Java)

I have a set of facts something(a),something(b),something(c), and I want to write all of them to a file.

I'm here:

```
testStreams :-
open('gnuprologstream.test',write,FileStream),
(
    something(X),
    write_term(FileStream,something(X),[]),
    fail
);
write(done),
close(FileStream).
```

I'm probably only too tired to think straight.

Please help.

Comment: "Please help."  What is your *question?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
testStreams :-
open('gnuprologstream.test',write,FileStream),
(
something(X),
write_term(FileStream,something(X),[]),
fail;
write(done)
),
close(FileStream).
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
?- tell('gnuprologstream.test'), listing(something), told.
```

This works in SWI-Prolog, I'm not sure about GNU Prolog.